# 9 patch background force to center content

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

- If I use 9 patch background drawable in my layout content is centered. If I use normal layout drawable Is displayed correctly based on xml.
- If I use 9 patch drawable background in my layout, in Android Studio in design screen the content is viewed correctly but when I run the application on a device the content is centered.
- In addition to the problem of content being centered, there is also the problem that the width of the content is limited as can see in the image.
- Is view of list view child
- I want it look like in the XML (the content of the layout is not centered + no content width limitted)

In device:

[image]

In xml:

[image]

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/unknown"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/chatleft"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout17"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView16"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView16">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView83"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:text="asdasd asd as" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

GetView:

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.chatitem, null);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Do you still see the problem if you change your `inflator.inflate` call to use `inflate(R.layout.chatitem, parent, false)` ?

Comment: Is custom adapter, "inflate" not exists. Inflator is getLayoutInflater() from activity.

Comment: I'm saying instead of using the `LayoutInflater.inflate(int, View)` method, use the `LayoutInflater.inflate(int, View, boolean)` method (and pass in `parent` and `false` for the second and third arguments). It's a drop-in change to the code you posted.

Comment: The error is still happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in a fresh project. I wonder if there's a style/theme being applied to your project's `TextView`s or `RelativeLayout`s

Comment: Text view or relative layout has not style, style for activity is:     <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>